# Cordova Windows 10 UWP Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am porting a navigation app to Windows 10 UWP and am struggling to work out how to implement Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution within the Cordova environment and am looking for any pointers or clues into how to make this work. The app is Angular/Ionic. Can we use a Javascript call to Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution or do we need a plugin in c# or similar to register for ExtendedExecution?

I have looked at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution but do not fully understand how to imeplement this in Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The app is Angular/Ionic. Can we use a Javascript call to Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution or do we need a plugin in c# or similar to register for ExtendedExecution?

You also could use `ExtendedExecution` api in your Ionic project. Because, the `Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution` Namespace is applicable for JavaScript within `Windows` environment. And I have translated a part of c# code to JavaScript that you could refer to. For more you could refer to [Postpone app suspension with extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution).

```
document.getElementById("btnClick").onclick = function (evt) {
    if (cordova.platformId == "windows") {
        var ExtendedExecution = Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution;

        var newSession = new ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionSession();
        newSession.reason = ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionReason.unspecified;
        newSession.onrevoked = function (args) {

        }

        newSession.requestExtensionAsync()
            .then(function (result) {
                switch (result) {
                    case ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionResult.allowed:
                      // do some stuff  
                     break;
                    case ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionResult.denied:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }, function (err) {
                var abc = err.message;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the Javascipt documentation on this and could not find any for these methods. Can you point me towards the javascript documents as the only ones I can find a c++, c# there appears to be no details for JS?

Comment: In the official document does not have the above code,  I converted c # to JavaScript according to JavaScript grammar rules.